# xcode iOS CoreData simple relational data retrieval

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, core-data

I have two tables in my coredata model (have more but keeping the example simple) employees and departments. An employee belongs in a department and a department contains many employees. Here are the table definitions:

```
Employee
================
employeeID int32
firstName string
lastName string
departmentID int32

Department
================
departmentID int32
departmentName string
```

Im just wondering what is the cleanest way to retrieve all Employees and their departmentName?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be designing your schema as if it was a database. Please do not do this. It is not necessary and antithetical to how CoreData works. You should get rid of your ID fields. Simply declare the appropriate relationships in the model and then all you have to do to get the department for an employee would be:

```
myEmployee.departmentName
```

Fetching all of the employees would just be done like this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
    entityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
    initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
[sortDescriptor release];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *array = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (array == nil)
{
    // Deal with error...
}
```

This was taken from the docs. If you are using ARC then change the code accordingly.

Comment: What about if I need to backup my coredata to the "cloud" than rehyrdate it? How do you serialize the coredata database with relations in tact? I can easily see how to serialize my current coredata database to xml/JSON with foreign keys.

Comment: Also this is really just a convert from a .net application. So implementing a new relational setup is more work the benefit.

Comment: In that case you might want to consider whether or not CoreData is right for you. Using SQlite with a wrapper like FMDB might be more appropriate.

Comment: Just to clarify on my last statement, serializing CoreData with relationships intact is not trivial from what I have heard. At the end of the SQLite (some people use MYSQL2 as well) is probably your best option.

Comment: if I did want to use coredata, what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: If you want, as you said, to get all the employees and their department name, the answer above is correct. If you mean instead to get all employees by a specific department name, in CoreData you have to fetch the Department first, and use it in a different fetch. Otherwise, if you already know the departments name, you can build a set of fetched properties.

Comment: If you want to use coredata then you should do it just like I originally posted. I really believe thought that with the requirements you laid out you will be better off using a database. If you REALLY want to use CoreData then you should use it as intended, otherwise you are going to run into problems, especially with regards to serialization.